# Form does not work with clicking Enter button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a problem with `enter` button. I have a form. And form works very correctly, if I click submit button. I want that when the user clicks `enter` button, form has to works, but it does not. I changed from `button onclick` to `form onsubmit` but it does not work.

My form

```
  const [login, setLogin] = useState({});

  const handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setLogin((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };


  let loginUser = async (e) => {
    setLoading(true);
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      let response = await auth().post("/login", { email: login.email, password: login.password });
      if (response.status === 200) {
        setLoading(false);
        setUser(response.data);
        localStorage.setItem("authToken", JSON.stringify(response.data.token));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
 <form onSubmit={loginUser}>
                <div className="email-login">
                  <div className="form-input">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input
                      className={error ? "error-input" : ""}
                      type="email"
                      name="email"
                      id="email"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder="Enter your email"
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-input">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input
                      className={error ? "error-input" : ""}
                      type="password"
                      name="password"
                      id="password"
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      placeholder="Enter password"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              <button
                disabled={selectTab === "email" && login.email === "" && login.password === ""}
                type="submit"
              >
                Login
              </button>
        </form>
```

And also If I click the `enter` button, it was disabled.

Comment: So why would it submit if the button is disabled?

Comment: @epascarello when inputs are empty, the button must be disable

Comment: So what do you expect it to do? Why would it submit an invalid form?

Comment: If the button is disabled, enter is not going to submit a form. So if you have a bug if the button is not becoming enabled.

Answer (score -1):

The provided form should work correctly with both the submit button and the Enter key. When using a form element with an onSubmit event handler and a button of type="submit" inside it, pressing the Enter key while focusing on an input field should trigger the form submission by default.

However, if you are still having issues with the Enter key, you can try adding an event listener to handle the Enter keypress explicitly. You can add the following code to your component:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const handleEnterPress = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      loginUser(event);
    }
  };

  document.addEventListener("keydown", handleEnterPress);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleEnterPress);
  };
}, [loginUser]);
```

This code snippet uses the useEffect hook to add a keydown event listener to the document. When the Enter key is pressed, it calls the loginUser function. The event listener is removed when the component is unmounted.

But before doing this, make sure the issue is not related to other parts of your code, as the provided form should work as expected by default.